# SQL update by inner join

Tags: sql-server-2005

Say I have two tables and would like to update the records in t1 only for those records that exist in t2.

```
ID = int, all others varchar

t1
id<PK>,sample,variable,status,notes

t2
sample,variable
```

I can select the subset from t1 by joining on t2

```
Select Sample FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.Sample = t2.Sample AND t1.Variable = t2.Variable
```

But what is the syntax to convert this to an update statement that does not pull update values from t2?  (My values do not derive from t2; t2 merely limits which records should be updated.)

```
UPDATE t1
SET Status=N'Complete',Notes=N'Lots of notes here'
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.Sample = t2.Sample AND t1.Variable = t2.Variable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost got it:

```
UPDATE t1Aliased
SET Status=N'Complete',Notes=N'Lots of notes here'
from t1 t1Aliased 
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1Aliased.Sample = t2.Sample 
AND t1Aliased.Variable = t2.Variable
```

Comment: Hmmm, thought I'd tried that.  Maybe it was the alias on the From table...Anyway, thanks!

Comment: If you could "Accept" so that this question is marked as answered, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Sure, looks like there's a 5-10 minute minimum before Acceptance is allowed.